# c# How to use Delegate in method with multi return

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, methods, delegates

I dont know why this code didnt work.

1. Only "a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4" is displayed in console.
2. myclass.a didnt work. why?

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace po
{
public delegate void godmode(int a, int b, out int c, out int d);

public class Class1
{
    public  int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
}

public class Program
{
    Class1 myclass = new Class1();
    Program pro = new Program();
    // myclass.a didnt work


    static void go1(int a, int b, out int c, out int d)
    {
        c = a + b;
        d = (a + b) * 10;

    }
    static void go2(int a, int b, out int c, out int d)
    {
        c = a;
        d = b;

    }
    static void go3(int a, int b, out int c, out int d)
    {
        c = a * 100;
        d = b * 200;
    }


    static int outofgod(int a,out int result1,out int result2, godmode beaman)
    {
        int b = a*2;
        int c = a*3;
        int re1, re2;

        beaman(b,c,out re1,out re2);

         result1 = re1 * 10;
         result2 = re2;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;

        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("a = {0}.....b = {1}..... c = {2}.... d = {3}",a,b,c,d);


        godmode mode1;
        godmode mode2;
        godmode mode3;

        mode1 = new godmode(go1);
        mode2 = new godmode(go2);
        mode3 = new godmode(go3);

        outofgod(a,out c,out d,mode1);

        Console.WriteLine("a = {0}.....b = {1}..... c = {2}.... d = {3}", a, b, c, d);

        outofgod(a, out c, out d, mode2);

        Console.WriteLine("a = {0}.....b = {1}..... c = {2}.... d = {3}", a, b, c, d);

        outofgod(a, out c, out d, mode3);

        Console.WriteLine("a = {0}.....b = {1}..... c = {2}.... d = {3}", a, b, c, d);

    }
}
```

}

---

**

myclass is isntanc of Class1. so i want to use a of instance"myclass" .
but when i type myclass, nothing appear.

Comment: The code as posted just does not compile. If fixed up a bit - works fine. Please provide [MCVE] (there is no need for 3 version of delegates for example) and ask *one* question per post.

Comment: make `Class1 myclass = new Class1();` static. there is no need to have instance of Program inside program it self. so remove `Program pro = new Program();`. cant debug because im not your debugger. also try not to use meaningless names. because it is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are static. You cant access non static field from static method.

```
static void YourMethod(....) // notice static keyword
{

}
```

To solve this problem you can make myclass static field.

```
static Class1 myclass = new Class1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use it like this

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static int a;
    public static int b;
    public static int c;
}
```

and then you can access the variables like

```
Class1.a
```

because if you normally try to do this will be

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'myclass'

Answer (score 0):

myClass is an "instance variable" since Program class is not static. Also, since your methods are static you can not access to a instance variable, you should to do this:

```csharp
public class Program
{
  Class1 myClass = new Class1();

  public Class1 MyClass{get{return myClass;}}
}

static void godmode()
{
  Program p = new Program();
  var myClass = p.MyClass;

}
```

But it sucks. So if you want to use Class1 you'll have to instantiate it  inside the static method.